# How to make a http request with a protobuf payload in Python

Tags: python-3.x, http, protocol-buffers

I have a service that exposes two REST APIs which exchange protobuf messages (payload). Up until now, I've worked always with HTTP/JSON, and in Python by using the requests and json packages is very easy to make HTTP requests with a JSON payload. I'm struggling to understand how to make a request having a protobuf message in the payload. I think to have searched enough on the Internet without any significant result. 
Has somebody had experienced this? Can she/he share some example?

Specifically, I have a `message_pb` which is the protobuf message object I instantiate (based on the python code generated by the protobuf-compiler) and fill in with my data.

I've tried to make a PUT request by using the requests package as follows:

```
requests.put(url, data=message_pb, header={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

This is the Traceback I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 126, in put
    return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 460, in send
    for i in request.body:
TypeError: 'ObjectStatistics' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Try to change Content-Type header to {'Content-Type': 'application/x-protobuf'}

Comment: Try this: `data=message_pb.SerializeToString()`

Comment: @ZaytsevDmitry : that would defeat the purpose of using protobuf right?

Comment: @Jominer : were you able find a way for this?

Answer (score 6):

Zaytsev Dmitry's comments seemed to do the trick for me.

```py
resp = requests.put(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/protobuf'}, data=message_pb.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: This is the correct answer per the protobuf documentation: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#parsing-and-serialization

Comment: @rectrec369 How do we send the payload here? I am not getting it. ```{ "first_name": "Jhon", "last_name": "Beck"} ``` its in json format. But when we use ```'Content-Type': 'application/protobuf'``` how do we send the same type payload ? what will be the format should HTTP request carry ? How do we send request from a API client like Postman ?